# Android Keeping Track of Button Selections

Tags: android

I have written some code in java that will guess a number based on the user's selections. It's pretty simple code. I am trying to integrate this code into an android app, by displaying the different number set each on different pages. The user will then click "Yes" if their number is in the set, or "No" if it isn't, and they'll then be redirected to another page.

The problem is I don't know how to keep track of their selections across the pages so that I can run the "If" statements based on their values as shown in the original code. Is there a simple way to keep track of whether they click "Yes" or "No" across the pages?

**This is my java code**

```
public class BinaryGame 
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        String set1, set2, set3, set4, set5, another = "y";
        int num, num1, num2, num3, num4, rand, number = 0, count = 0;
        final int PER_LINE = 4;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println ("Think of a number between 0 and 31. And I will be able to figure it out.");
            System.out.println ("");

            rand = generator.nextInt(2);
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                for (num = 16; num < 32; num++)
                {
                    System.out.print(num + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                    System.out.println ();
                }

                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set1 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set1.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                number += 16;
                else
                number += 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                for (num = 0; num < 16; num++)
                {
                    System.out.print(num + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                    System.out.println ();
                }

                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set1 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set1.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    number += 0;
                else
                    number += 16;
            }

            System.out.println ();

            rand = generator.nextInt(2);
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                for (num1 = 8; (num1 < 16) || (23 < num1 && num1 < 32) ; num1++)
                {
                    System.out.print (num1 + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                    System.out.println ();
                    if (num1 == 15)
                    num1 = 23;
                }
                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set2 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set2.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                number += 8;
                else
                number += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (num1 = 0; (num1 < 8) || (15 < num1 && num1 < 24) ; num1++)
                {
                    System.out.print (num1 + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                    System.out.println ();
                    if (num1 == 7)
                    num1 = 15;
                }
                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set2 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set2.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                number += 0;
                else
                number += 8;
            }
            System.out.println ();
            rand = generator.nextInt(2);
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                for (num2 = 4; (num2 < 8) || (11 < num2 && num2 < 16) || (19 < num2 && num2 < 24) || (27 < num2 && num2 < 32); num2++)
                {
                    System.out.print (num2 + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                        System.out.println ();
                    if (num2 == 7)
                        num2 = 11;
                    if (num2 == 15)
                        num2 = 19;
                    if (num2 == 23)
                        num2 = 27;
                }

                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set3 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set3.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    number += 4;
                else
                    number += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (num2 = 0; (num2 < 4) || (7 < num2 && num2 < 12) || (15 < num2 && num2 < 20) || (23 < num2 && num2 < 28); num2++)
                {
                    System.out.print (num2 + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                        System.out.println ();
                    if (num2 == 3)
                        num2 = 7;
                    if (num2 == 11)
                        num2 = 15;
                    if (num2 == 19)
                        num2 = 23;
                }

                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set3 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set3.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    number += 0;
                else
                    number += 4;
            }
            System.out.println ();
            rand = generator.nextInt(2);
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                for (num3 = 2; (num3 < 4) || (5 < num3 && num3 < 8) || (9 < num2 && num3 < 12) || (13 < num3 && num3 < 16) || 
                    (17 < num3 && num3 < 20) || (21 < num3 && num3 < 24) || (25 < num3 && num3 < 28) || (29 < num3 && num3 < 32); num3++)
                {
                    System.out.print (num3 + " ");

                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                        System.out.println ();
                    if (num3 == 3)
                        num3 = 5;
                    if (num3 == 7)
                        num3 = 9;
                    if (num3 == 11)
                        num3 = 13;
                    if (num3 == 15)
                        num3 = 17;
                    if (num3 == 19)
                        num3 = 21;
                    if (num3 == 23)
                        num3 = 25;
                    if (num3 == 27)
                        num3 = 29;
                }
                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set4 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set4.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    number += 2;
                else
                    number += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (num3 = 0; (num3 < 2) || (3 < num3 && num3 < 6) || (7 < num2 && num3 < 10) || (11 < num3 && num3 < 14) || 
                (15 < num3 && num3 < 18) || (19 < num3 && num3 < 22) || (23 < num3 && num3 < 26) || (27 < num3 && num3 < 30); num3++)
            {
                System.out.print (num3 + " ");

                count++;
                if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                    System.out.println ();
                if (num3 == 1)
                    num3 = 3;
                if (num3 == 5)
                    num3 = 7;
                if (num3 == 9)
                    num3 = 11;
                if (num3 == 13)
                    num3 = 15;
                if (num3 == 17)
                    num3 = 19;
                if (num3 == 21)
                    num3 = 23;
                if (num3 == 25)
                    num3 = 27;
            }
            System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
            set4 = scan.nextLine();
            if (set4.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                number += 0;
            else
                number += 2;
            }
            System.out.println ();
            rand = generator.nextInt(2);
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                for (num4 = 1; num4 < 32; num4 += 2)
                {
                    System.out.print (num4 + " ");
                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                        System.out.println ();
                }
                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set5 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set5.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    number += 1;
                else
                    number += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (num4 = 0; num4 < 32; num4 += 2)
                {
                    System.out.print (num4 + " ");
                    count++;
                    if (count % PER_LINE ==0)
                        System.out.println ();
                }
                System.out.print ("Is your number in this group? y/n: ");
                set5 = scan.nextLine();
                if (set5.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    number += 0;
                else
                    number += 1;
            }
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("You chose: " + number);
            number = 0;
            System.out.print ("Would you like to play again? y/n: ");
            another = scan.nextLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As a side comment, you can significantly reduce the size of your program by rethinking your algorithm and removing the duplication (use functions), and thus making it more understandable and easier to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by pages you mean Acvities with in the same application, then you would want to look at `SharedPreferences` ([class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)).

In the Activity where the button is pressed, you might want to do somethinge like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSHaredPreferecne("buttonPrefs");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.editor();

editor.PutBoolean("btnYes", true);
editor.commit();
```

Then, when you need access this (again with in the same application):

```
SharedPreferecnes myPrefs = getShharedPreferences("buttonPrefs")
boolean yesIsPressed = myPrefs.getBoolean("btnYes", false)    // the second param is a default return value if preference is not found
```

`SharedPreferences` can used anywhere in tha same application, as long you have the correct name.